# Good Drupal IDEs?

Tags: drupal, ide

Are there any Drupal IDE's with syntax highlighting, and possibly intellisense, function descriptors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Netbeans PHP - http://www.netbeans2.org/features/php/index.html

Best IDE for php and if the code has good comments, the provides documentation when using functions.

Comment: Here's the plugin for NetBeans Drupal http://drupal.org/node/327486

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of tools listed on [this page](http://drupal.org/node/147789), a few of which link off to Drupal plugins.

Textmate and Eclipse stand out for that. Otherwise, the page looks like a grand list of what Open Source PHP Developers might consider using.

Answer (score 1):

A dev named Chris Charlton created a series of great extensions for Dreamweaver specifically for Drupal.  http://xtnd.us/

Comment: Dreamweaver is awful! Several years of IT support for it and Contribute.